# In how many ways can the letters in WONDERING be arranged with exactly two consecutive vowels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can the letters in WONDERING be arranged with exactly
>   two consecutive vowels

I solved and got answer as $90720$. But other sites are giving different answers. Please help to understand which is the right answer and why I am going wrong.

**My Solution**

Arrange 6 consonants $\dfrac{6!}{2!}$
Chose 2 slots from 7 positions $\dbinom{7}{2}$
Chose 1 slot for placing the 2 vowel group $\dbinom{2}{1}$
Arrange the vowels $3!$

Required number of ways:
$\dfrac{6!}{2!}\times \dbinom{7}{2}\times \dbinom{2}{1}\times 3!=90720$

**Solution taken from http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=6126)**

[image]

**Solution taken from http://myassignmentpartners.com/2015/06/20/supplementary-3/
[image]**

Comment: Can you explain your working. Just putting down your calculation doesn't tell us why you chose to do them.

Comment: @sorry, edited the calculation and added the details. pl help.

Comment: I will point out that the solution in the excerpt solves a different problem. Your problem asks for "exactly two consecutive vowels", the excerpt's solution allows 3 consecutive vowels as well. As it says at the end "with at least two adjacent vowel"

Comment: $ReverseFlow, but in the first excerpt , they do 120960 - 15120 which count exactly two consequent vowels only. So this approach also must be right I guess.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that strategy works for the counting. One sec.

Comment: What is  "arrange 6 consonants"?

Comment: There are 6 consonants in which 2 are repeating. so number of arrangements possible using them alone is 6!/2!. this is what I meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48829/discussion-between-reverseflow-and-kiran).

Comment: @Kiran Your answer is correct.

Comment: but then, the answer given in the first website (also given by @barak manos) must also be correct, right? why that is going wrong?

Comment: @Kiran You answer is right and their answer is wrong. I have added my explanation below.

Comment: Checked with Python, the answer is indeed $90720$, deleted mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of arrangements with 3 consecutive vowels is correctly explained in the original post: the number is $15120$.

To find the number of arrangements with *at least* two consecutive vowels, we duct tape two of them together (as in the original post) and arrive at $120960$.

The problem with this calculation is that every arrangement with 3 consecutive vowels was double counted: once as $\overline{VV}V$ and again as $V\overline{VV}$. To compensate for this we must subtract $15120$.
The correct number of arrangements with *at least* two consecutive vowels is 
$120960-15120=105840.$

Therefore, correct number of arrangements with *exactly* two consecutive vowels is $105840-15120=90720.$

Comment: yes, it is. I am able to understand now. thanks for your help, i spent over 6 hours for this problem only. I have to improve a lot :(

Answer (score 1):

The total number of ways of arranging the letters is $\frac{9!}{2!} = 181440$. Of these, let us count the cases where no two vowels are together. This is $$\frac{6!}{2!} \times \binom{7}{3}\times 3! = 75600$$
Again, the number of ways in which all vowels are together is 15120. Thus the number of ways in which exactly two vowels are together is 
$$181440 - 75600 - 15120 = 90720$$